# Accessing my VMware Ubuntu client through Wi-Fi network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, portforwarding

I am trying to connect to my client VM through my home network but I am not able to do so. Hopefully I am able to explain my situation - it is way out of my field. :/ The client runs Ember-cli server.

Through the Virtual Network Editor and NAT settings, I am able to expose the client's Ember port (4200) to the same port of my Host. So hitting `localhost:4200` shows the ember application.

My host is ethernet-connected to the router and has an ip 192.168.1.110 which I can access through the Wi-Fi network. What I am trying to achieve is hitting `192.168.1.110:4200` through the Wi-Fi network and exposing the Ember application.

I am not sure if what I want to achieve has to do with my router's forwarding, with VMWare settings, or anything else. :/

Edit: Host is running Windows 10.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21378423/2948109

Comment: In forwarding rules you should use ip of your VM and from other devices IP of your PC

Comment: Will check on these later on today

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ping 192.168.1.110` from your machine where you installed, if it's reachable then you should not be having any problem with accessing `http://192.168.1.110:4200`.

Comment: I can access it from the host, but cannot from my iphone on the wireless network.. :/

Comment: For testing purpose, you can turn off the firewall settings.