# Docker Swarm running inside VM workstation 15 player doesn't accept worker connection

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, docker-swarm, vmware-player, ubuntu-19.04

I am running a docker swarm manager in VM Workstation 15 player with NAT(VM: Ubuntu 19.10, Host: Windows 10). I ran `docker swarm init --advertise-addr 223.181.240.48:2377` on my mangager vm. Now i copied to the token and used it on my my other vm that is running on another node and another network with NAT. it returns the following error:

> Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined.
>   The attemp to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the
>   "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node.

Then i tried googling for error and got to know that the problem may arise due to firewall and i might have to unblock the port.Also, as i am using NAT, i have to either use automatic bridge or port forward.First, I tried using bride(in vm setting, i changed network to bridge), but when i tried "my ip",the results were same in both host machine and vm(223.181.240.48).So, i tried port forwarding with NAT,i went to C:/ProgramData/VMware/vmnetnat.conf and added the following line

```
[incomingtcp]
2377:192.168.172.2:2377
```

192.168.172.2 is my vm's net gateway address. Then i again ran the docker swarm command, copied to my other vm. Now, i got the following error:

> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code =Unavailable desc = all
>   SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection
>   error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp
>   233.181.240.48:2377: connect: connection refused"

Then i tried sudo ufw allow 2377/tcp to unblock port in vm. Then retried the whole procedure again. Now i am again receiving the timeout error. Did i miss something in the middle? or did something wrong?  And what is the difference between the ip i receive through a "my ip " google search and the ipv4 i receive in wired connection setting(dhcp on).

Comment: I don't believe nodes communicating between each other through NAT is a supported configuration. The nodes need to be able to communicate between each other by IP address without a firewall over several ports. You'll need some kind of network between the nodes, perhaps a VPN like wireguard would work.

Comment: @BMitch - "what is the difference between the ip i receive through a "my ip " google search and the ipv4 i receive in wired connection setting(dhcp on)." - i need some clarification here, i am extremely new to virtual machines and ubuntu.

Comment: One is a public IP that others on the internet see your requests on, and the other is a private IP behind a NAT router that cannot be directly accessed.

Comment: @BMitch So, how am i supposed to connect to my vm? which one should i use?

Comment: You'll need some kind of network between the nodes, perhaps a VPN like wireguard would work.

Comment: That seems to be wrong syntax for _vmnetnat.conf_. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386841/how-to-do-port-forwarding-on-vmware-player-14-1-2-ubuntu-18-04-guest-windows-1) for a working example .